# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sin\bigl( \frac{x^2}{n} \bigr)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I have to show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sin\bigl( \frac{x^2}{n} \bigr)$ is pointwise convergent for $-\infty<x<\infty$, and that it is uniformly convergent on any interval of the form $[-K,K]$ for $0<K<\infty$.

I can show that the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is pointwise convergent, but I can't seem to link the convergence of the sequence to the convergence of the series.
Likewise with the uniform convergence of the series.

I cannot find a valid series for doing the Weierstass' M-test.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Show if the series $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \sin(\frac{x}{k})$ converges uniformly or not.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851307/show-if-the-series-fx-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k-sin-fracxk) – just replace $x$ by $x^2$

Comment: I see, I also managed to due the second part, since for a given K, I can show that $\lvert 1/n\sin(x^2/k) \rvert \leq \lvert x^2 \rvert /n^2 \leq K^2/n^2$, given me a convergent series.
But what about the first part? Is it trivial that if I have a pointwise convergent sequence $\{f_n\}$ the associated sereis $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ is also pointwise convergent?

Thank you for the pointer, it seems that my search skills are insufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usince the fact that $(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):\bigl|\sin(x)\bigr|\leqslant|x|$, one gets that$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac1n\sin\left(\frac{x^2}n\right)\right|\leqslant\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^2}{n^2}.$$Therefore, if $x\in[-K,K]$, one has$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac1n\sin\left(\frac{x^2}n\right)\right|\leqslant\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{K^2}{n^2}$$and this proves that the series converges uniformly on $[-K,K]$.

Comment: Thank you, but what about the first part of the question regarding pointwise convergence? See my comment above.

Comment: Your comment is nonsense. Are you suggesting that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges $\implies$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges? What happens if each $f_n$ is the constant function $1$?

Comment: That's true. So does it follow the fact that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n = 0$?

I guess my main question is: How do I show that the series is pointwise convergent for $-\infty < x < \infty$?

Comment: @RasmusSøgaardChristensen I proved that it converges uniformly and that implies that it converges pointwise. And, no, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=0$ is not enough. Consider the possibility that $f_n=\frac1n$.

Comment: I guess it is the way the question is phrased that confuses me then.

So it converges uniformly on $[-K,K]$ for $0<K<\infty$, but since we haven't specified any $K$ it follows that the series is uniformly convergent and hence pointwise convergent on $]-\infty,\infty[$?

Comment: @RasmusSøgaardChristensen Of course not. The function $f(x)=x$ is bounded on any interval $[-K,K]$, but you don't deduce from that that it is bounded on $\mathbb R$, do you?

Comment: Thank you, but then I'm back to my original questen; How do I show that the series is pointwise convergent for $-\infty<x<\infty$?

Comment: @RasmusSøgaardChristensen $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac1n\sin\left(\frac{x^2}n\right)\right|\leqslant\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^2}{n^2}=\frac{\pi x^2}6$.